# each wait until finish $.ajax , and then continue

Tags: jquery, ajax, each

```
    function genTask(elem){
    elem.each(function(){
        $this=$(this).parent('.cntTasks');
        var pattern=/taskId-(.*)$/
        var idTask=$this.attr('id').match(pattern);
        var data='id_task='+idTask[1];
        if(typeof jsVar2 !='undefined') data+=jsVar2;
        $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: domain+"/view_tasks/gen_tasks/",
             dataType: 'html',
             data: data,
             success: function(dt){
                $this.find('.contChildTasks').html(dt);
                childs=$this.children('.taskDesc').find('.has_child');
                if(childs.length!=0)
                    genTask(childs);
                }
             }
        });
        $this.find('.taskDesc').show();

    });
}

if(typeof jsVar2 !='undefined') genTask($('.cntTasks .has_child'));


});
```

how is possible to make  `$.each` to wait until action `$.ajax` will be finished  , and then continue loop , i cannot get $this var , because it has the last value ,  sorry for my English , THANK YOU !!!!

Comment: Maybe you could set the `async` attribute of $.ajax to `false`? See: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Option 1: Switch to next element in your array in the `success` handler.

Option 2: Make ajax requests synchronously:

- global:

  ```
   $.ajaxSetup({ async: false });
  ```
- or directly in the request:

  ```
   $.ajax({
       async: false,
       type: "POST",
       url: domain+"/view_tasks/gen_tasks/",
       dataType: 'html',
       data: data,
       success: function(dt){
          $this.find('.contChildTasks').html(dt);
          childs = $this.children('.taskDesc').find('.has_child');
          if(childs.length != 0) {
              genTask(childs);
          }
       }
  });
  ```

Answer (score 0):

try putting `ajaxsetup({async:false});` before your each loop
then after the loop reset it back to true so your future ajax request can still be `async`

Answer (score 0):

Set `async` to false on the `$.ajax` call.

Answer (score 0):

In your `$.ajax` call add `async: false` and it will send a blocking request.