# Synchronous .each() Ajax issue with incrementally widening div

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, synchronous

I have a script that's 99% finished .. But I can't seem to get the very last portion of it figured out.  My `async: false` is functioning correctly, as the ajax calls are made in succession in the function `billAllDeadbeats`.  The issue I am having is simply with the widening of a `div` upon each succession.  The script **does** make each `ajax` call in `synch` so would it stand to reason, that in the `success` method, that would also be `synchronous`?  My progress bar is waiting until the `billAllDeadbeats` has finished instead of incrementally widening.

```js
 $(document).on('click', '#billAllDeadbeatsButton', function () {
              hideElements().then(billAllDeadbeats);
});



        var hideElements = function() {
            var defer = $.Deferred();

            alert('hideElements() called');
            $('#collectAllHeader').hide();
            $('#collect_all_invoices_progress_wrapper').hide();
            defer.resolve();

            return defer;
        };
        
        
        
        var billAllDeadbeats = function() {
            var defer = $.Deferred();

            alert('billAllDeadbeats() called');
            setTimeout(function () {
                var current_count = 0;
                var percent = 0;
                var total_count = 0;
                $('.collectDeadbeat').each(function () {
                    total_count++;
                });

                // #################################  START EACH
                var def = [];
                $('.collectDeadbeat').each(function (i, obj) {
                    current_count++;
                    percent = current_count / total_count * 100;
                    def.push(prepareLayer($(this).attr('data-deadbeat-id'),$(this).attr('data-deadbeat-balance'),percent));
                });
                defer.resolve();
            }, 500);

            return defer;
        };
        
        function prepareLayer(id,balance,percent) {
            $.ajax({
                async: false,
                type: "POST",
                url: "collectAll.php",
                dataType: 'html',
                data: {id:id, balance:balance},
                success: function(id,balance){
                    $('#pay_all_loader_inner').css("width", Math.round(percent) + "%");
                    console.log(Math.round(percent));
                }
            })
        }
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#banner-message {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}

button {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

#pay_all_loader_inner{
  height:30px; background-color:#FF0000; width:0%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="collectDeadBeat" data-deadbeat-id="1" data-deadbeat-balance="100"></div>
<div class="collectDeadBeat" data-deadbeat-id="2" data-deadbeat-balance="200"></div>
<div class="collectDeadBeat" data-deadbeat-id="3" data-deadbeat-balance="300"></div>
<div class="collectDeadBeat" data-deadbeat-id="4" data-deadbeat-balance="400"></div>
<div class="collectDeadBeat" data-deadbeat-id="5" data-deadbeat-balance="500"></div>
<div class="collectDeadBeat" data-deadbeat-id="6" data-deadbeat-balance="600"></div>
<div class="collectDeadBeat" data-deadbeat-id="7" data-deadbeat-balance="700"></div>
<div class="collectDeadBeat" data-deadbeat-id="8" data-deadbeat-balance="800"></div>
<div class="collectDeadBeat" data-deadbeat-id="9" data-deadbeat-balance="900"></div>


<div id="banner-message">
  <p>My Progress</p>
  <button id="billAllDeadbeatsButton">GO!</button>
  <div id="pay_all_loader_inner"></div>
</div>
```

I have read and read, and all the questions on SO point to the same thing .. Set the `ajax` call to `asynch = false`, and use `then` with `defer` to run my separate functions synchronously. Where am I going wrong?

I have used the following as references:

[Make synchronous function in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27012556/make-synchronous-function-in-javascript)

[each wait until finish $.ajax , and then continue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8657401/each-wait-until-finish-ajax-and-then-continue)

And they've gotten me super close, but no cigar.  How can I make my progress bar incrementally follow the returns on the ajax calls?

Comment: with synchronous code, there's no time for rendering

Comment: @Jaromanda X -- OK  -- If that's the case .. How do I go about what I am trying to accomplish?

Comment: chain the promises (or defered's as jQuery likes to call them) - `$.ajax` does return a promise

Comment: the defered returned in `hideElements` is pointless by the way - as is the one in `billAllDeadbeats`

Comment: Something like - https://jsfiddle.net/mh5rL87q/ - sorry, more like https://jsfiddle.net/mh5rL87q/2/ (missed a return)

Comment: The script in the JSFiddle calls all the ajax calls simultaneously -- instead of waiting until one finished to run the next one.

Comment: check the **second** fiddle - I forgot a return

Comment: actually - https://jsfiddle.net/mh5rL87q/5/ is probably even more correct

Comment: That last one is super close, although it's making 2 ajax calls together at a time.  The reason I need it one at a time is our billing API only allows one connection at a time.

Comment: not sure why it would do 2 at a time rather than say all of them at once like when I forgot the return

Comment: [here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pyc7hLvj/) that uses **real** Pormises rather than the buggy rubbish jquery passes off as promises (in early versions at least)

Comment: by the way, there was a problem with https://jsfiddle.net/mh5rL87q/5/ but it wouldn't have caused what you claim `return prepareLayer($(this).attr('data-deadbeat-id'),$(this).attr('data-deadbeat-balance') ,percent);` needed to be `return prepareLayer($(obj).attr('data-deadbeat-id'),$(obj).attr('data-deadbeat-balance') ,percent);`

Comment: I've used that code with a "dummy" ajax - https://jsfiddle.net/apwszeqx/10/ and, well, it definitely executes one "AJAX" at a time

Comment: hhmmm  -- I am getting doubles for every call ... -->   https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hJ99.png

Comment: So the same request twice. That's some other issue.

Comment: put a console.log at the top of the `click` handler - see if it's called more than once

Comment: Strange --> https://i.stack.imgur.com/gAFeU.png  clicked once .. 2 calls is intermittent  ...  I suppose this will be a separate question.